# How to branch from deleted branch in git

Tags: git, branch

I think I have made a mistake in regard to my git workflow. I did the following:

1. branched from *develop* branch to branch *foo*
2. created a pull request -> merged *foo* into *develop* -> *foo* branch automatically deleted
3. continued working on *foo* branch locally
4. want to branch from *develop* (have not pulled) to new branch, but keep the code I'm working on

I have not committed anything, nor have I pulled anything.

How can I solve this predicament?

Comment: Branching "from a branch" is a useful metaphor in most workflows, but under the hood you only ever branch from some commit. Later deleting the label that once *was* on that commit is unconsequential. What in your context prevents you from just rebasing your local `foo` on a updated `develop`?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: So what is stopping you from switching to local `develop`, and creating a new branch based on it?

Comment: could you add some ascii art branching graph  to explain your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have not pulled the develop branch locally yet. In that case you can just switch to develop branch by doing git checkout.

```
git checkout develop
```

---

If the local changes you have done are not conflicting with the changes in develop branch the checkout will be smooth.

If there are conflicting changes then checkout will fail. In that case you will want to stash your local changes and then pop them back on whatever branch you want later on.

1. Stash the current changes

```
git stash
```

2. Switch to develop and create new branch (I am assuming you want to do this)

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b your-new-branch
```

3. Pop the changes on this branch

```
git stash pop
```

You may get the conflict again. You may resolve, add and commit to mark it resolved.

---

About your confusion. Don't worry about local branch being deleted from remote.

Even though remote branch is deleted, the branch still exists on the local repo. Rather, given git is **distributed VCS**, every repo can exist without remote being present and its branches and commits will be present until deleted locally.

You can avoid all the complicated process at top and just do git checkout and it will create a branch from your current commit without giving you any conflict.

When on your current branch which is deleted from remote.

```
git checkout -b your-new-branch
```